# Is there any way to redirect stderr output from a command run with “start” in the Windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, redirect, stderr

I have a program that I want to automate runs for, since it takes awhile to complete. For some reason it outputs everything to stderr instead of stdout, and I'd like to check on its progress, so I find myself needing to redirect stderr output within a start command.

I tried this:

```
start "My_Program" "C:\Users\Me\my_program.exe" --some --presets --for --my_program.exe --output "C:\Users\Me\output_file_for_my_program" "C:\Users\Me\input_file_for_my_program" 2>"C:\Users\Me\my_program_output.log"
```

But it turns out that the redirect is being picked up by start, so that I get a 0-byte file with the result of "start" - namely, nothing. Is there any way to make the output redirection attach in some way to the output of my_program?

I've experimented with escaping, and neither "^2>" nor "2^>" seem to work.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using <code>start</code> and not just <code>"C:\Users\Me\my_program.exe" --some --presets --for --my_program.exe --output "C:\Users\Me\output_file_for_my_program" "C:\Users\Me\input_file_for_my_program" 2>"C:\Users\Me\my_program_output.log"</code>?

Comment: I'm calling this in a different program, and it needs to be run in the background. start is the only way I've been able to do that, which is strange since you'd think that the output would be redirected to the logfile but for some reason it's not.

Basically, I have no idea why that doesn't work, but it doesn't for some reason.

Comment: Please do not open the same question on multiple sites: http://serverfault.com/questions/56865/is-there-any-way-to-redirect-stderr-output-from-a-command-run-with-start-in-the

Comment: Apologies, I realised after opening the question on serverfault that it wasn't the correct place to ask that question.

I'll see if I can't close it.

Comment: Actually you have an answer there. I would wait until it get moved then close this one.

Answer (score 0):

If "Workaround Oriented Programmming" is acceptable (it probably is, you are programming Windows Batch lol), you could put the problematic code line in another .BAT file, without any "start" and then "start" this other BAT.

Comment: Yeah, at this point I'm just looking for a way to get this to work. I'd rather not use batch files, because this particular command needs to be run multiple times with different input and output files, as well as different arguments, but as a last resort, I'll try that.

Comment: Well I built a "YouTube" once, using ffmpeg to compile the videos. I made a script to compile all videos from a folder from any format to .flv
Maybe it helps: http://pastebin.com/f6af803b

Comment: Shal: You can pass arguments to batch files as well. In that case you could just have `someprogram %*` in your batch which will pass any arguments to the batch to the program.